# settimeout() function is not working in ie 6,7,8

Tags: javascript

i have the problem with my `setTimeout()` function.
`setTimeout()` function is not working in IE 6,7,8.
even i use jquery ready function that is also not working in IE.
can anybody tell me any alternate.

Comment: Please provide the code and explain the problem.

Comment: Can you post the relevant JavaScript?

Comment: `setTimeout()` works fine in those browsers. Show some code and we might be able to tell you what is wrong. Otherwise this question will likely be closed within 5 mins.

Comment: A perfect example on how a question should not be asked. -1.

Answer (score 1):

It's `setTimeout`, with a capital T.

Assuming `lat` and `lon` can be resolved, you should wrap the getlocation function call inside an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function () { getlocation(lat,lon); }, 100);
```

What you are doing is:

```
setTimeout(<the output of the getlocation call>, 100);
```

Unless `getlocation` returns a new function (or function code as a string), this is not going to work.

Making function calls instead of passing function references is a very common error that you should be careful about.

Comment: this is my function now you can help me. setTimeout(getlocation(lat,lon), 100);

Comment: but it is still not working in ie6, ie7, ie8. it works in ie9.

Comment: thanks for your replying. I am finding the solution there is a ',' problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running your getlocation function instantly rather than in 100ms.

Change it to:

```
setTimeout(function() { getlocation(lat,lon) }, 100);
```

setTimeout requires a function as the first parameter, you were passing the result of getlocation.

Comment: but it is still not working in ie6, ie7, ie8. it works in ie9.